# Can Delphi (dbExpress) use SHOW TABLES across Schemas?

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, delphi-xe2, dbexpress

I trying to write a small database management app to compare our live and dev database schemas

At the moment I can use a single TSQLconnection to get the list of Schemas on the MySQL (5.0) server, the problem comes when I try and directly access the schemas.

I want to select a schema and show all the tables from that schema in a listbox.

The procedure below compiles, but fails with a "You have an error in your syntax" message when it hits the ExecSQL.

```
procedure TDM.GetTables(schemaname: string);
begin
   with SQLQuery1 do
   begin
      SQL.Clear;
      SQL.Add('SHOW TABLES FROM ' + schemaname);
      ExecSQL;
   end;
end;
```

*Schemaname* comes from a tcombobox seeded using `GET SCHEMAS` and looks to be being passed OK.

I've tried the above with Open rather than ExecSQL and get the same error.  I've also tried to append a `;` to the end of the statement.

Unless I'm being blind I'm wondering if the issue is with dbExpress

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was a combination of the nest of the `with` and my choice of parameter names.

TSQLQuery has a **property** called `schemaname` and I think that the compiler was getting confused with my **parameter** of the same name.

Catching this wasn't helped by the debugger correctly reporting the value of the parameter in the inspector...

Answer (score 3):

There must be another reason that this don't work .
Normally this should work;

```
 SQL.Add('SHOW TABLES FROM ' + schemaname);
```

instead, you can try that :

```
with SQLQuery1 do
   begin
      close;
      SQL.Clear;
      SQL.Add('SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'+
              ' WHERE table_schema = "'+schemaname+'"');
      Open;
   end;
```

Comment: That's the route I've gone for with the Columns after using TSQLCOnnection.GetTableNames which also works.  This is better for what I'm trying to do, but doesn't explain *why* `SHOW TABLES` isn't working...